# sIFR not showing up on my page?

Tags: sifr

I am trying to use sIFR and am having problems making it show. I have an h1 tag on my page, followed by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
        sIFR.replaceElement("h1", "flash/revolution.swf", "#000000", null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

I have both sIFR style sheets attached, as well as the sIFR js file. So what happens is that my h1 tag just disappears. So I think the js file is working in hiding, but not replacing the font with the font in the .swf file. I am pretty sure that my swf file is working since I had it working on a different page, but I can't seem to make this work. Do I need to specify anything in the provided css file?

Thanks a lot for any tips on where to look to make this work!

Answer (score 1):

Simple idea, but is "flash/revolution.swf" accessible by the page?  I've made the simple mistake of creating clean URL's and forgetting to make it "/flash/revolution.swf."

Comment: yeah, I think it is. I embedded the swf file somewhere else on the page to test that and it had the same path. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the code right before the `</body>`, rather than right after the `</h1>`.